# After modifying models with Flask-Permissions UserMixin, models can't find foreign key relationship

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask-Permissions library for setting some basic permissions system.

In the User class I replaced `db.Model` with `UserMixin` from Flask-Permissions.

Everything should pass, but SQLAlchemy throws error

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'fp_user' and 'user'.

That's not looking good. I thought that `UserMixin` already inherits from `db.Model`.

**This is my current code**

```
Class User(UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    storage_hash = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    profile_picture = db.Column(db.String(255))
    gender = db.Column(db.Enum('male', 'female', name='gender'))
    registered_on = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    last_activity = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    role = db.Column(
    db.Enum('student', 'teacher', 'secretary', 'debuty_director', 'director', 'supervisor', name='user_role'),
    nullable=False)
    credit = db.Column(db.Float, default=0)
    school_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('school.id'), nullable=True)
    file = db.relationship('File', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
    class_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('class.id'), nullable=True)
    storage = db.relationship('UserStorage', uselist=False, backref='user')
    payments = db.relationship('UserPayments', uselist=False, backref='user')

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, email, password, school_id=None, role='student', gender='male'):
        UserMixin.__init__(self, role)
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.email = email
        self.storage_hash = strgen.StringGenerator('[\w\d]{20}').render()
        os.mkdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + self.storage_hash)
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(
        password, app.config.get('BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS')
    ).decode('utf-8')
        shutil.copy(app.config['IMAGES_FOLDER'] + 'resources/users/default_{}.png'.format(gender),
                '{}/{}/'.format(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], self.storage_hash))
        self.profile_picture = 'user_files/{}/default_{}.png'.format(self.storage_hash, gender)
        self.gender = gender
        self.registered_on = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.role = role
        self.school_id = school_id
        storage = UserStorage()

        db.session.add(storage)
        db.session.commit()

        self.storage_id = storage.id
```

Why do I get this exception?

Comment: You `User` model class should inherit from `db.Model` and `UserMixin`.

Comment: That's not true because UserMixin already inherit from db.Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in tablename. My `__tablename__` is set to `user`, but in `Flask-Permissions` `UserMixin` table is set to `fp_user`. I have to delete the table name or replace it in library.

Even better option is to use fork of `Flask-Permissions` [`SQLAlchemy-Permissions`](https://github.com/LouisTrezzini/sqlalchemy-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.

The version installed by `pip  install Flask-Permissions` is outdated (2014). The `UserMixin` class has been updated in 2016 so that your `User` classe could inherit it.

Instead you should install the last version available on github:
`pip install git+https://github.com/raddevon/flask-permissions.git`